# Auto-delete messages from a certain contact when received

Tags: sms-blocking

Is there an app or any other way to auto-delete specific contacts/numbers' text messages when received?

Comment: Why don't you just block them through your carrier?  It'll save you the hassle (and SMS charges if you don't have a text plan).

Comment: @MatthewRead blocking through your carrier is far from something you can expect in every country. In Sweden I know for a fact that several major carriers do not offer the service.

Answer (score 0):

When you block a number, it automatically blocks all incoming calls and messages from that number and also deletes all of the conversations you have had with them. This is so they won't be able to reach you at all and no matter what they do. they won't be able to contact you.

When you block a person, it also erases their phone number. If you try to call or text them, it also won't go through since you have already blocked them. There will be no problem since neither of you can contact each other. It is the best way to go.

Comment: For anyone using a Samsung mobile phone, unfortunately the phone keeps the messages from the number blocked and stores them finding blocked messages in settings. This is a seriously strange idea and not helpful if you are trying to not see messages that are upsetting or aggravating you. It also shows when a blocked number has called you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you don't need an external app for this, it has been a feature of Android since long time. Messages from blocked senders are deleted upon arrival so they don't even appear on your device.

Go to *Phone -> More -> Settings -> Call blocking -> Block list* and add the number you want to block.

Alternatively, go to your phone log or SMS list and select *More -> Block number*.

Answer (score -1):

You can just download an app from Play store - it can block text messages and even phone calls.

Try [Truecaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller), add the contact to the *Blacklist* which will lead to the block.